# How do I batch assign values to a property of objects returned by the fetched results controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, properties, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Ok so I have a bunch of objects that exist in my database, they have all fields completed except for two... as the value could not be determined at the time that the objects were created.

Now I want to insert code in a `payment received method` that will write the SAME value (eg. $120.50) to the blank fields for ALL objects returned by the fetchedResultsController.

This is what I had previously done to create a NEW object and set the values for the properties.

```
newInvoice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Invoice" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];


[newInvoice setValue:productTextField.text forKey:@"itemCode"];
```

What code do I use to set the value of ALL returned objects, for the properties below which are currently blank in the SQL database?

```
[newInvoice setValue:amountPaidLabel.text forKey:@"amountPaid"];
[newInvoice setValue:paymentMethod.text forKey:@"PaymentMethod"];
```

I hope that made sense, any input would be kindly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a method on your invoice class...

```
- (void)updateEmptyPaid:(NSNumber *)aValue {
  [self setValue:aValue forKey:@"amountPaid"];
}
```

... do the same for the payment method and then you can do....

```
[myInvoices makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(updateEmptyPaid:) withObject:newValue];
[myInvoices makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(updatePaymentMethod:) withObject:newValue];
```

Where myInvoices is an array of the results from NSFetchRequest.

Comment: Hey thanks I have tried implementing your code but I must be doing it wrong, i get the following error: `[Invoice updatePaymentFields:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b5af70`
This is the method `-(void)updatePaymentFields:(NSString*) aValue {NSLog(@"I'm inside Update Payment Fields");[self setValue:aValue forKey:@"amountPaid"];`
This is where it gets called `- (IBAction)saleCompleteButtonTapped:(id)sender {
[mutableFetchResults makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(updatePaymentFields:)  withObject:amountPaidStr];
}`
Would you have any idea why I would be getting this error?

Comment: I was getting the error because updatePaymentFields was intact in the Invoice class like you said it should be, I had it in my firstViewController